# how to make the logic inside a custom vue directive run only when that element is clicked on?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

Right now, the directive that I hook up to any element, is executed when the page loads.
This is not something I want. I want the directive to run on clicking that element.
How can I go about something like this?

```
  directives: {
            'new-dir': {
                bind(el, binding, vnode) {
                    el.style.cursor = "pointer";
                    console.log(vnode);
                    if(vnode.tag == 'div'){
                                ...something       }
                    else if(vnode.tag == 'a') {
                      console.log("its a link and clicked");
                      if(vnode.data.attrs.target == "_blank"){
                        console.log("external link");
                      } else{
                        console.log("internal link");
                      }
                    } else if(vnode.tag == 'input') {
                       console.log("its an input ");
                       console.log("type = " + vnode.data.attrs.type)
                       console.log("placeholder = " + vnode.data.attrs.placeholder);
                    }
                }
            },
  }
```

Comment: What makes you want to use a directive for this? In the same situation, I would probably add a `v-on:click` listener instead.

Comment: Sure, there is the on:click directive. But I am creating a custom directive because I want to access the data on the element using vnode to pass through as parameters to another function. I plan to use this directive extensively. I don't want to create an on:click and then hook a function to it and pass the parameters too for every element. It's to reduce the code and time(to type code) to repeat the same thing again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directives **must** be bound to an element and the directive code runs at that time.

If you want specific logic to run within a click handler, you need to register one

```js
directives: {
  "new-dir": {
    bind: el => {
      el.style.cursor = "pointer"
    },
    inserted: (el, binding, vnode) => {
      // store a reference to the click handler on the element
      // this is primarily so you can remove it later
      el.newDirClickHandler = e => {
        console.log(vnode);
        if (vnode.tag == 'div') {
          // something
        }
        if (vnode.tag == 'a') {
          console.log("its a link and clicked");
          if (vnode.data.attrs.target == "_blank") {
            console.log("external link");
          } else {
            console.log("internal link");
          }
        }
        if (vnode.tag == 'input') {
          console.log("its an input ");
          console.log("type = " + vnode.data.attrs.type)
          console.log("placeholder = " + vnode.data.attrs.placeholder);
        }
      }

      // register the click handler
      el.addEventListener("click", el.newDirClickHandler)
    },
    unbind: el => {
      // unregister the click handler
      el.removeEventListener("click", el.newDirClickHandler)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Phil. Why would we unbind the click handler ?

Comment: It's just cleaning up.